# Published MAUI app doesn't work with access database

Tags: .net, ms-access, maui, oledb

I have a .NET MAUI app that connects to a local access DB (don't ask me why my employer uses access), it works when I run it from Visual Studio in both debug and release modes. When I published it, it doesn't work and it crashes. I don't know how to create a log file for the app to see why it crashes.

I know it crashes when it tries to connect to the database because I added to the app that it should display some text in every part of code it runs, it crashes at the line it tries to connect.

I use a `OleDbConnection` with connection string

> @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\access\accessdb.accdb"

I load a data table based on the primary key value passed in to a `Entry`. When I pass in a string it doesn't crash because the PK needs to a int and I have a if statement to check if it's a int, but when I pass in a int it tries to connect to the database and it crashes.

My xaml code:

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*,*" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto,*">
    <Label x:Name="MainLbl" Text="" FontSize="Header"
           VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
           Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Add a ID"/>
    <Entry x:Name="StudentIdTxt" Placeholder="Add here" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="Start" TextChanged="StudentIdTxt_TextChanged"/>
    <Grid x:Name="StudentLst" IsVisible="False" ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="*,*,*,*,*" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Name"/>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding StudentName}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My c# code with the text in label for debugging at what line it crashes.
The reason why I added the `async` and `await` is because when I added a int it crashed right away and I wanted to debug at what line it actually crashed.

```cs
DataTable localDT = new();

public StudentSearch()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainLbl.Text = "0";
}

private async void StudentIdTxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(100);
    MainLbl.Text = "1";
    await Task.Delay(100);
    ShowData();
}

private async void ShowData()
{
    MainLbl.Text = "2";
    await Task.Delay(100);
    if (int.TryParse(StudentIdTxt.Text, out int id))
    {
        MainLbl.Text = "3";
        await Task.Delay(100);
// This is where it crashes in published version and it shuts down the program.
// In debug and in release when running from visual studio it continues and shows the data.
        localDT = Load(id);
        MainLbl.Text = "4";
        await Task.Delay(100);
        if (localDT != null && localDT.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            MainLbl.Text = "5";
            await Task.Delay(100);
            StudentLst.IsVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            StudentLst.IsVisible = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StudentLst.IsVisible = false;
    }
}

private DataTable Load(int primarykeyvalue)
{
    DataTable dt;
    OleDbConnection con = new();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\access\accessdb.accdb";
    con.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = $"select * from StudentProgramRewards where StudentId = {primarykeyvalue}";
    dt = GetDataTable(cmd);
    return dt;
}

private DataTable GetDataTable(OleDbCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

I have more code than this so ignore the binding in the `Entry`. That's not causing the issue.

Comment: to start with, add some basic exception handling to your code that will help you identify the source of the crash

Comment: @Jason Why didn't I think of this... This will need to wait for Monday but I'm leaving this question as is, maybe someone has encountered this issue before. Could it be that the compiled published code has different connection than unpublished?

Comment: What platform are you publishing to? If you using the ACE data engine, then of course the application will work on windows, but of course not Android or iOS. If you goal to use this on anything other then windows, then you need to use say Sqlite, since there is not a working ACE (access data engine) for anything else but windows.  Sqlite is .net code, so it can run on Android or iOS, but the Access data engine is windows code, not .net code, and thus it will work and run only on the windows platofrm.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I'm publishing to windows. It works as it should when it's in debug or release mode but when I publish it to the same PC it crashes.

Comment: Force the project to x86,  or x64 if using access x64 bits.  Don't use any cpu

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Thanks will try on Monday and update